# SQLite - select every row from all tables where a column name exists

Tags: sqlite

I need to extract all rows from every table that has the column `imgAssetURL` to add to a pre loading system.

I think in essence something like:

```
SELECT imgAssetURL FROM *
```

What are my options?

Comment: Why not centralize the information about images into one table?

Comment: The definitions for all tables are located in the `sqlite_master` table.  You would have to read those definitions, figure out which tables have the column in it, and run a query on each of those.  See http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master

Comment: What you want to do is not really supported by the relational model. What you should instead do (and this is easy to say with the benefit of hindsight) is create a table called something like `image_asset` and put the URLs in that, then link other tables to rows in it via foreign keys. Then this would be as simple as selecting from `image_asset`.

Comment: @Tom: almost all databases support a data dictionary and as Robert stated correctly `SQLITE_MASTER` contains what *davivid* needs. Knowing all tables a `View` might be quite handy (with `SELECT` ... `UNION SELECT` ...)

Comment: @Robert, thanks using the `sqlite_master` I have created a loop that extracts what I need. You should make an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definitions for all tables are located in the `sqlite_master` table.  You would have to read those definitions, figure out which tables have the column in it, and run a query on each of those.

See http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master